# case statement which taken match of same status in mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb-10.4

I have 2 tables, One table has status and another one table has mark and id.

**table1**

| id | versin | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | ram |
| 2 | 1 | ram |
| 3 | 2 | ram |
| 4 | 3 | ram |

**table2**

| sid | status | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Pass | ram |
| 2 | Pass | ram |
| 3 | Pass | ram |
| 4 | Fail | ram |

this is my query,

```
select id, 
       case when status ='fail' or status='N/A' 
            then max(versin)-1
            when status = 'PASS' 
            then max(versin)
            else max(versin) 
            end as versin
from table1 A
inner join ( select max(versin) as mxversin 
             from table1 
             group by name ) B
    on B.id = A.id and B.mxversin = A.versin
left join table2 C 
    on C.name= B.name
```

In this scenario, I got correct versin, but the id is not matching.

I got,

table

| id | versin | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | ram |

I need

The result table should be

| id | versin | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 | ram |

Please help me out from this scenario, thanks in advance

Comment: Your query returns an error indicating `B.id` is unknown, as there is no `id` column defined in the subquery  that formed B.

Comment: Describe the task. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Actually, I need data like e.g One user creates 4 versions of data like 0,1,2,3, And 0 to 2 versions are approved and 3 is in pending status. I need to show only the approved status of the maximum version. with the corresponding id of the version.
So I prepared 
case when table2.status = pending then max(table1.version)-1 
when table2.status = approved then max(table1.version)

At this stage, I could not get the corresponding id of the versions, I got 0 version's id and max(version) data. 

Thanks in advance @Akina

Comment: 1) Add these explanations into the question (see "Edit" link under it). 2) Your question is not accurate. Does the column `sid` in `table2` is one which you refer on as `id`?

Comment: Answer should come from table 1 - Id,  version, name. And we can't use desc limit 1, because name column have various value like ram, vjy, akin like that. Second table Sid just auto increment id, matching with name only.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.sid AND t1.name = t2.name
WHERE t2.status = 'Pass'
ORDER BY t1.versin DESC LIMIT 1
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e5c80834ad2662a47254c777adba1355

Comment: Answer should come from table 1 - Id,  version, name. And we can't use desc limit 1, because name column have various value like ram, vjy, akin like that. Second table Sid just auto increment id, matching with name only.

Comment: @Vijay You have told now that the model provided in the question is not adequate. Fix this and create adequate model which contains everything mentioned in your comment. Create a fiddle with source data, provide the link to it and show desired output for it with detailed explanations.